# What is wrong with my equation for an ellipse?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I'm drawing an ellipse on the screen by generating lots of random y-values for every x-value (this creates bristles of a paintbrush I can later use to draw strokes).

Since wikipedia says the equation of an ellipse at the origin is:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$

I used basic algebra to solve for

$$y = \pm\sqrt{b^2 \left( 1 - \frac{x^2}{a^2}\right)}$$

The problem is the resulting random points are not an ellipse at all, it's a stepped inverted mess like this:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why my equation isn't working please?

---

Below is my Javascript code for Paper.js if it helps:

```
for (let x = -width/2; x < width/2; x += bristleSize)
    for (let bristleCounter = 1; bristleCounter < numBristlesPerX; bristleCounter++)
        bristles.push(getRandomPointInEllipseAtX(x, width, height));

function getRandomPointInEllipseAtX(x, width, height)
{
    const halfWidth = width / 2;
    const halfHeight = height / 2;
    const heightAtX = 2 * Math.sqrt(Math.abs(halfHeight^2 * (1 - (x^2 / halfWidth^2))));
    const y = randomPN() * heightAtX; // -1 to 1 * height
    return new p.Point(x, y);
}
```

Comment: There's something wrong with your code. You should get the upper half of an ellipse if you plot the points satisfying the second equation.

Comment: Can you check that randomPN function? I can't find any documentation on it

Comment: @user1001001 Doesn't the code take care of that with the ```-1 to 1 * height```?

Comment: How does your Q show no option for edit ?

Comment: In Javascript, `^` is probably some bitwise operator. Have you tried replacing `x^2` with `x*x`, etc.?

Comment: Yeah, randomPN seems like the likely culprit. Also, why is there a $2*$ when computing the height at $x?$

Comment: Nothing is wrong about your math. It can be a bug, since I used the exact same formula for making an ellipse on a different programming language.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang +1. `^` is the XOR operator. For exponentiation, one can use `Math.pow` or `**` - or simply use `x*x` instead of `x**2`/`Math.pow(x,2)`.

Comment: Thank you, yes, it should be x**2, not x^2. Facepalm. Sorry everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The strongest guess is that the `randomPN()` function generates a continuous random number in $[-1,1]$, while it should generate random numbers in $\{-1,1\}$. Try to use a command like `2*floor(randomPN())+1`.